# Prevent child element from overflowing the parent without fixed heights

Tags: html, css, reactjs, angular, sass

So I am building an angular component like this. I need a header, some buttons and then a table followed by some more buttons, followed by a footer.

```
<my-component>
  <div>Hello I am the header</div>
  <some-stuff class="flex flex-col">I contain some buttons</some-stuff>

  <the-problem-child>
    <table>I contain a table<table>
    <div>I contain some buttons</div>
  </the-problem-child>

  <div>Hello I am the footer</div>
</my-component>
```

The problem is, that the table can have very few or very many rows, meaning that in some cases it overflows the `<my-component>`, which I want to prevent and instead make the table scrollable while keeping everything else visible.
As the component is used inside other components, I cannot use vh to set a max-height. I would also like to not use fixed heights and use all of the available space, before the table overflows itself.

How can I achieve this without setting a max-height to the table or other parts?

I have tried using flex-box and various attributes, but could not figure out how to stop `<the-problem-child>` from overflowing the parent `<my-component>` as I dont want to set a fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS property fit content, in order to dont overlap the father ones.

```
                               width: fit-content
```